# Many-many EF Core relationship - why does it try to insert an entity to a different table?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm new to Entity Framework Core, and I'm trying to insert a row into a table which has a many-to-many relation with another table.

I'm using the code-first approach, so I did not explicitly created a join table, letting EF Core do it better than me.

The problem is: I try to add a row to `tableA` (using `AddAsync`); that row/object already contains all the required initialized attributes, included a list of objects of `tableB` type; when I execute the query (`SaveChangesAsync`), I get this error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tableB' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I don't understand why EF Core is trying to insert a new row in `tableB` (throwing an exception since the value already exist). I just want it to insert the row in `tableA` and the relative keys in the join table.

Can anyone help me please?

I'm looking for an answer since hours now and I'm not able to find anything useful.

Comment: When you're inserting tableA, make sure the tableB object inside is null.

Comment: IIRC, `AddAsync` is for internal use in EF only, to add an entoty to the DbContext you should only have to use `Add` (makes sens really, since all it does is adding an object to the DbContext change tracker, no DB operation is done at that moment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF (Core) works on top of the change tracking concept. To correctly handle existing entities EF's DbContext needs to track them otherwise it will consider them as new ones and will try to insert new rows into the database. Consider the following example:

```cs
TableA a = new ...;
TableB iKnowItExistsButCtxDoesNot = new TableB // can be mapped from frontend for example
{
  Id = SomeExistingId
};

a.TableBs.Add(iKnowItExistsButCtxDoesNot);
context.TableA.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This will lead to EF trying to insert new row for `iKnowItExistsButCtxDoesNot`. One of the workarounds would be to attach it before adding `a`:

```
// ...
context.TableB.Attach(iKnowItExistsButCtxDoesNot);
context.TableA.Add(a);
// ...
```

Read also:

- [Change Tracking in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)
- [Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)