# ASP.NET Core MVC SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_User'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get an error when uploading a video:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_User'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is (831769c6-fc01-4203-a345-0aa12702b95e)

This is my code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(VideoUploadViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);

        var video = new Video
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Description = model.Description,
            DurationSeconds = model.DurationSeconds,
            CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
            User = user,
            UserId = userId
        };

        await _videoRepository.AddVideoAsync(video, model.VideoFile);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var categories = await _categoryRepository.GetAllCategoriesAsync();
    ViewBag.Categories = categories;

    return View(model);
}


public async Task AddVideoAsync(Video video, IFormFile videoFile)
{
    try
    {
        if (videoFile != null && videoFile.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(videoFile.FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "videos", fileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await videoFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            video.FilePath = fileName;
        }

        _context.Videos.Add(video);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(video.FilePath))
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "videos", video.FilePath);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

```
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Название видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Название видео")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Длина 'Названия' не должна превышать 100 символов")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Описание видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Описание видео")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Длина 'Описания' не должна превышать 500 символов")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Продолжительность видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Продолжительность видео")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Значение 'Продолжительность' должно быть неотрицательным")]
    public int DurationSeconds { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Файл видео")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Выберите видеофайл")]
    public IFormFile VideoFile { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Категория видео")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Категория видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<View> Views { get; set; }

    public Video()
    {
        UploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Likes = new List<Like>();
        Views = new List<View>();
    }
}
```

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Email' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Некорректный формат 'Email'")]
    public override string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Логин' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Длина 'Логина' должна быть от 3 до 50 символов")]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Дата регистрации")]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SearchHistory> SearchHistory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WatchHistory> WatchHistory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WatchLater> WatchLaterList { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public ICollection<View> Views { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        RegistrationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Videos = new List<Video>();
        SearchHistory = new List<SearchHistory>();
        WatchHistory = new List<WatchHistory>();
        WatchLaterList = new List<WatchLater>();
        Notifications = new List<Notification>();
        Views = new List<View>();
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Likes = new List<Like>();
    }
}
```

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public UserRepository(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
}
```

If you do not pass the User to the model, then the Video will have the User = null property. If you pass it, then for some reason it tries to create a new user with the data from the User that I passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest option would be to just skip assigning the `User` property (assigning `UserId` should be enough to save the `Video` entity to the database in correct state):

```cs
var video = new Video
{
    Title = model.Title,
    Description = model.Description,
    DurationSeconds = model.DurationSeconds,
    CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
    // User = user,
    UserId = userId
};
```

It seems that `GetUserByIdAsync` either uses another context instance or performs [non-tracking query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).

Another options you can look into:

- [Attaching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76946448/2501279) the user object instance to the context manually (for example in the `AddVideoAsync` call)
- Fixing the `GetUserByIdAsync` so it would use the same context instance and would perform tracking query on it (without seeing the full code it would be hard to tell how to achieve that)

Comment: if you do not pass the User to the model, then the Video will have the User = null property. If you pass it, then for some reason it tries to create a new user with the data from the User that I passed. and I have models for each user with their own videos. _videoRepository uses HouYun3Context. _userRepository uses UserManager<User>

Comment: @wag_jr 1) _"if you do not pass the User to the model, then the Video will have the User = null property."_ - and? If you need it to not be null then assign it after saving  (updated the answer with other options worth looking into) 2) _"it tries to create a new user"_ I have added 2 most likely reasons for such behavior.

Comment: I added UserRepository. Let me clarify what I want: I need the user to have a connection with his downloaded videos, and now using only UserId it takes the user correctly, but doesn't associate that video with the user. In the debug, the model has a video property User = null, UserId = correct

Comment: When fetching the video, make sure you are loading related user with Include method